# How can I save a 500 KB video to SD card with Teensy 4.1?

Tags: video, embedded, teensy

As you may know, Teensy 4.1 comes with an onboard SD card slot. What I'm curious about is how I can use Teensy to save a 500 KB video package to the SD card it has on board. What is the easiest way to do this? In what format should I send the video? I apologize for being very new to these topics. Thank you very much in advance.

I am trying to write a 500 KB telemetry video file to the SD card with Teensy.

Comment: Remove the card, place it in a PC, copy the file.  That is the "easiest".  You probably don't want the "easiest", you need the _most appropriate_ that works in your application.  The answer will depend on the source of the data.  For example if it is form a camera attached to the board or if it is a file over a network or USB or whatever.  It is probably the wrong question.  You probably need to be clear on the software framework you are using.  Presumably it includes a file system, you receive data somehow, you write it to a file. Done,

Comment: The file "format" will be whatever suits your application, neither the SD card nor the data transmission medium care.  That is a matter of producer and consumer - what format do that generate and/or consume.